# SPARQL query a label and return the corresponding instance category

Tags: sparql, wikidata

For example, I use this SPARQL

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?jobLabel WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?person wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072.
  ?person wdt:P106 ?job.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 30
```

can query below result:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F04Ud.png)

My question is, how can I get those jobs' corresponding upper first instance label?

Like astronaut is:**profession**

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZZmM.png)

Engineer is: **profession**

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jala.png)

And my wanted query result would be like:

person   //    personlabel     //job_field

wd:Q320     // Michelle Bachelet    // profession

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you're asking for...your query already return women with their profession. what else do you want?

Comment: @AKSW returned is the occupation, like she is a astronaut. What I want is this job category, astronaut belongs to profession, and I want to get this bigger class - profession.  ~~

Comment: I don't know why you want this, but what prevents you from doing `?person wdt:P106 ?jobTmp. ?jobTmp wdt:P31 ?job` then? Or `?person wdt:P106/wdt:P31 ?job .` ? I mean it's just one triple pattern more...